# Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not writable, admin has to fix directory permissions! Exiting

Tags: iis, moodle, php-7

```
unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();
$CFG->dbtype    = 'sqlsrv';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'my remote db ip address';
$CFG->dbname    = 'remote database name';
$CFG->dbuser    = '****';
$CFG->dbpass    = '**********';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
    'dbpersist' => 0,
    'dbport' => 1433,
    'dbsocket' => '',
);
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/LMS';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'C:\\inetpub\\LMSdata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';
$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;
```

This is my configuration in config.php. I'm using moodle 3.2 in IIS with php 7. Remote SQL server version 2012.

Comment: Please help me. Every time I refreshed it shows me this error. After reloading it run properly but after changing anything when i hit save or update or cancel button, the arise again.

Answer (score 1):

The webserver does not have write permission to the folder ( C:\inetpub\LMSdata).Please modify the permission of the dataroot folder and allow write permission. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IIS 10, you can do like this.
[image]

The simple solution is to this problem is to change the NTFS permissions on the moodledata folder to allow write/modify to any user who is using moodle (I just set ours to domain users).

Answer (score 0):

How to allow your moodle data write permission.
Please follow these steps
For that please go to /var/www/moodledata or if any path where you defined the moodle data
then just paste this command

> sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

I hope this will solve your permission problems

Answer (score -2):

Make sure 'inetpub' directory exists

Comment: Yes, these directories exist.